# Gauss' law in differential form for a point charge

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to understand how the integral form is derived from the differential form of Gauss' law.
I have several issues:

1) The law states that $ \nabla\cdot E=\frac{1}{\epsilon 0}\rho$, but when I calculate it directly I get that $ \nabla\cdot E=0$ (at least for $ r\neq0$).

2) Now $ \iiint\limits_\nu \nabla\cdot E d\tau $ should be zero no matter what the value of the divergence is at 0, since the divergence is zero everywhere but 0 (in contrast to the law which states it is non-zero).

3)

a. The proof itself goes on to use the divergence theorem to state that for any volume $\nu$, $ \iiint\limits_\nu \nabla\cdot E d\tau = \iint\limits_{\partial\nu} E d a $, however the divergence theorem requires E to be continuously differentiable everywhere in $\nu$ (it is not differentiable at 0, let alone continuously differentiable there).

b. The function cannot be corrected in any way at 0 since the derivative goes to infinity around 0.

c. The point 0 cannot be removed from the integrated volume because the divergence theorem requires that the volume of integration be compact.

d. In light of the former I don't see how the divergence theorem can be used here.

Comment: You should take a look at the mathematical concept of [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). They have special rules, when it comes to integration. And the easiest way to rigorously prove the result is to introduce a regularization of $E$, such that its divergence is continuously differentiable. Then you apply Stokes' theorem (divergence theorem) and you remove the regularization to obtain the result.

Comment: More on [int vs diff form of Gauss's law](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+differential+integral+law+gauss*).

Comment: The problem of a point charge is: it gets infinite self energy. nevertheless, I think your question has to be dealt with Dirac delta function, but I am not quite familiar with it. anyway, you can work things the other way around, define divergence as an ratio of "field flux out of a closed surface" and "volume of that closed surface", and let volume sink to zero. then what you get is just a derivative.

Comment: That one point at $r=0$ makes all the difference in the world.  As you have discovered, "conventional" calculus has problems with it.  You need a different calculus, as @yuggib has pointed out.

Comment: @yuggib Could you give the regularized definition of E? (if you have references that would be great)

Comment: @Shing This definition is equivalent to the one I gave when the function is smooth (reference is wikipedia (divergence)).

Comment: @TomM For example, you may mollify by convolution with a smooth function, the alternatives are many. Anyways, a modern approach to an equation like $\nabla\cdot E=\varrho$ is to consider its eventual solution in $\mathscr{S}'$, with the derivative intended in a weak (distributional) sense. You need some sort of boundary conditions of course to tackle the problem. The only point I see is to make sense of Stokes' theorem, of which I do not know weak formulations (i.e. for weak/distributional derivatives). But I think that with a mollification you should not have many problems

Comment: for you apply Stokes to the mollified function, and then remove the mollification. (I use this type of terminology because I see from other comments that you are a mathematician)

Comment: @yuggib My main problem is that the divergence function is zero almost everywhere (other than 0) for a point charge, and therefore it doesn't matter how you might correct it at 0, the integral won't change. If you change it at other places then it is no longer the divergence and you won't be able to use divergence theorems for it. If the divergence is seen in some other form that is not the original definition then all divergence properties must be reproved to be used.

Comment: @TomM Given a [mollifying sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, you take the function $E*f_n$ that is now continuously differentiable, and therefore $\nabla\cdot(E*f_n)$ is a true function. Then you apply Stokes' theorem on $\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot(E*f_n)d\tau=\int_{\partial \Omega}(E*f_n)da$. Finally, you take the limit $n\to\infty$ on both sides and obtain $1=\int_{\Omega}\delta d\tau=\int_{\partial \Omega}Eda$ as you wished.

Comment: If you want to avoid the sloppy definition of $\int_{\Omega}\delta$, you may think of defining $F(n)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot(E*f_n)d\tau$; then $F(n)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. The rest makes sense, provided $E$ is a function for which the surface integral makes sense (but that depends on which boundary conditions you have used to solve $\nabla\cdot E=\delta$, and therefore the regularity of the solution). And to be extremely pedantic, you need to be able to use Lebsgue's dominated convergence theorem on the right-hand side.

Comment: @yuggib 
1. The divergence is a real function even now (it is only undefined at 0). 2. The pointwise convergence of a series of functions does not imply the convergence of the series of the integrals to the integral of the pointwise limit.

Comment: 1. That is not the way of defining a point charge in a physically meaningful way; the meaningful way is with a $\delta$ distribution. 2. I know that. On the left hand side, you can make things explicit with a smart choice of mollifier, and prove the convergence a posteriori of the integral $F(n)$.

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436616/11127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What you've got totally right

> 1) The law states that $ \nabla\cdot E=\frac{1}{\epsilon 0}\rho$, but when I calculate it directly I get that $ \nabla\cdot E=0$ (at least for $ r\neq0$).

Awesome! You see, if you've derived this based on the $\vec E$ field of a Coulomb point charge, then $\rho = 0$ for $r \ne 0.$ So you're in agreement for all points except perhaps for the point at zero.

## Where things start to get fishy

> 2) Now $ \iiint\limits_\nu \nabla\cdot E d\tau $ should be zero no matter what the value of the divergence is at 0, since the divergence is zero everywhere but 0 (in contrast to the law which states it is non-zero).

Here's where the problem is occurring. The proper way to visualize the point charge, as a $\rho$, is a 3D Dirac $\delta$-function. The 1D Dirac delta-function is something which acts suspiciously like a function $\delta(x) = 0, x\ne 0$ but which has an infinitely high peak at $x=0$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}dx~\delta(x) = 1$. It of course is not a real function, but you can treat it that way because you can substitute in some real functions, like $\delta_s(x) = (2\pi s^2)^{-1/2} \exp[-x^2/(2s^2)],$ and then outside the integral you can take the limit as $s \rightarrow 0$ to get finite solutions which behave precisely in this way. Since the Gaussian function is also smooth, one can even define $\delta'(x), \delta''(x),\dots$ via $\delta_s'(x), \delta_s''(x),\dots$; they work like you would expect if you naively did integration-by-parts. Eventually, you can understand them in an algebra of "integral transforms" which are mostly defined by specifiying a real function to act as the "kernel" of the transform. The Dirac $\delta$-function comes about by adding a transform which can't be specified this way but which is still extremely important: the identity transform. It is precisely because it satisfies $\int_{-L}^{L} dx~\delta(x - x_0)~f(x) = f(x_0)$ that we adjoin it to our transform list; and in this mathematics of "distributions" you have that, for example, $[\delta(x)]^2 = 0.$

## Generalizing to 3D and getting a handle on the first Maxwell Equation

Since you can't multiply them meaningfully, the 3D $\delta$-function needs to instead be constructed in spherical coordinates as a different limit:$$\delta^3_s(r,\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{2\pi r^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}} ~ \exp\left[-\frac{r^2}{2s^2}\right]$$

To calculate the $\vec E$ field for this charge distribution, you need a result about $1/r^2$ force laws (you might e.g. have seen it in the context of gravity) which states that a *spherical shell* of mass $M$ averages out to have **no** field internally, while *externally* it behaves like all of its mass is located at its center. So the field on any spherical surface is given by calculating all of the charge inside of that sphere, using $\rho_{\text{point}} = q_0 ~ \delta^3_s(r,\theta,\phi).$ This enclosed charge at radius $R$ is:
$$q_s(R) = \int_{r<R} dV ~ q_0~ \delta^3_s(r,\theta,\phi) = 2~q_0~ \int_0^R \frac{dr}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}} ~ \exp\left[-\frac{r^2}{2s^2}\right].$$Defining $\chi(z) = \int_0^z \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-x^2/2)$ this is just $$q_s(R) = 2~q_0~\chi(R/s).$$ It's an integral that cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but that won't matter too much to us. Our recipe that the field is only due to the charge enclosed in the sphere of radius $r$, all acting like it's at the origin, means that the $\vec E$-field is purely radial and is $$\vec E = \frac{q_s(r)}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}~\hat r.$$Then [looking up the formula for divergence in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formulae) we find that here it simplifies to:$$\nabla\cdot\vec E = \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r (r^2 E_r) = \frac{q_0}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2} ~ \frac{2}{s} ~\chi'(r/s) = \frac{q_0}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2} ~ \frac{2}{s} ~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left[-\frac{r^2}{2 s^2}\right] $$
But of course this is just:$$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \frac{q_0}{\epsilon_0} ~ \delta^3_s(r).$$Now you can see: for the "real" 3D $\delta$-function, this divergence **is** zero for $r > 0$. But it contains a funky divergence **at** zero which encodes the point charge $q_0$ located at that point. And we can see this because all of what we wrote is exact! So we just make $s$ small but finite, say, $10^{-100}\text{ m}$ or so: all of this divergence happens in this space that's much, much tinier than anything we actually care about, and then outside of that space we get $\nabla \cdot E = 0$.

## Hop, skip, jump: QED.

So why, you may ask, did we *need* the 3D $\delta$-function in the first place? All we've really used is spherical symmetry and the fundamental theorem of calculus! The answer is, we're now **one step away from the general result**. The powerful feature of the 3D $\delta$-function is that for any continuous function $\rho(\vec r) : \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ we have: $$\rho(\vec r) = \int d^3r'~\delta^3(\vec r - \vec r') \rho(\vec r').$$ We declare that we're going to use the **principle of superposition** to sum up little forces $\vec E = \int d\vec E(\vec r')$ each due to a charge $dq_0 = \rho(\vec r')~d^3r'$ sitting at the point $\vec r'.$

Performing this integral we see that we can interchange with the divergence operator (it's the divergence with respect to $\vec r$, we're fundamentally integrating over $\vec r'$), so we have:$$\nabla\cdot\vec E = \int d^3r' ~ \rho(\vec r') \delta^3_s(\vec r - \vec r') / \epsilon_0.$$Taking the limit as $s \rightarrow 0$ we get simply:$$\nabla\cdot\vec E = \rho(\vec r) / \epsilon_0.$$

## Postmortem

> 3) a. The proof itself goes on to use the divergence theorem to state that for any volume $\nu$, $ \iiint\limits_\nu \nabla\cdot E d\tau = \iint\limits_{\partial\nu} E d a $, however the divergence theorem requires E to be continuously differentiable everywhere in $\nu$ (it is not differentiable at 0, let alone continuously differentiable there).
>
> b. The function cannot be corrected in any way at 0 since the derivative goes to infinity around 0.
>
> c. The point 0 cannot be removed from the integrated volume because the divergence theorem requires that the volume of integration be compact.
>
> d. In light of the former I don't see how the divergence theorem can be used here.

We use the divergence theorem when $s$ is still assumed to be finite, so there are no infinities and the result is exactly what we wanted. Then we get the result in the limit as $s\to 0,$ and then we **interpret** the resulting equation as universally valid because it (a) obeys the law of superposition and (b) reproduces the "correct" result again for the Coulomb force if we set $\rho = q_0 \delta^3_{s'}(\vec r),$ and take the limit as $s'\to 0$.

Comment: Are you saying that the divergence of the electric field is a delta?

Comment: BTW I'm totally comfortable with distributions so you can use those if it helps.

Comment: @TomM Yes, it is a 3D delta-function **for the Coulomb field of a point charge**, and it is that way because the charge density $\rho$ for a point charge is a 3D delta-function. The *reason* you're getting this infinity is because it's inherent in your assumption. When we shift to $\vec E(r) = (4\pi\epsilon_0)^{-1} \int d^3r' ~ \rho(\vec r') ~(\vec r - \vec r')/ |\vec r - \vec r'|^3$ to eliminate this assumption, we can then also get $\nabla \cdot \vec E = \rho$, because $\nabla \cdot (\vec r - \vec r')/|\vec r - \vec r'|^3 = 4\pi\delta^3(\vec r - \vec r'),$ if you like.

Comment: @TomM Hm. Actually, getting the latter formula is I guess a little tricky if you insist on not using the divergence theorem. Aside from the same trick as above (this time replacing the term with a Lorentzian $1/(u^2 + s^2)$ where $\vec u = \vec r - \vec r'$ followed by a "legit" application of the divergence theorem, I don't see an immediate way to show that that function behaves like a 3D $\delta$-function.

Comment: But the divergence for my version of the electric field can't be a delta function since it is a real function. It can be used anywhere - not only under the integral sign. Saying they are equivalent implies that either the delta function is a "real" function or that the divergence is not a real function (even though it certainly is, since you can compute it at any point other than 0).

Comment: @TomM: Your charge configuration ("a point charge at the origin") is singular. Thus the divergence of your field is singular. You can certainly compute that the divergence is 0 at every point other than the origin, but that's true of $\lim_{s\to 0} (2\pi s^2)^{-1/2} \exp[-x^2/(2s^2)]$ too -- and that's our old friend $\delta(x)$. "You can compute it at any point other than 0" is thus seen to be insufficient for concluding that something is a real function as opposed to a distribution.

Comment: There are functions that are not defined at 0... For instance the function 0 without a definition at 0. It's still a function just not defined at zero. The delta however is not a function. You can't define it anywhere because it isn't a function. To define it you have to use other tools. That is why these entities can't be equal. The divergence theorem assumes that the divergence is a function, not something that's not a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29179/discussion-between-chris-drost-and-tomm).

Comment: @TomM I didn't see you in chat, so I wanted to mention that I have asked [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437185/how-do-divergences-of-vector-fields-generate-distributions) on Math.SE asking for the particulars that you're looking for: how we can better define "divergence" so that when we give it the $\hat r / r^2$ field, the divergence will yield a distribution rather than an ordinary function.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you run into problems when trying to describe a point charge using a charge-density function $\rho(r)$. There are three ways around this:

1. What a pre-20th-century physicist would have done: Replace the point charge by a sphere of radius $R$ and total charge $q$. Everything is well-defined, standard calculus works just fine, and you can take the limit $R \rightarrow 0$ at the end, if you like.
2. What Dirac (and most modern physicists) would do: Ignore all the difficulties and treat the charge density as a (3-dimensional) [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta(r)$, which has $\delta(r) = 0$ for all $r \neq 0$ but $\int \mathrm{d}^3r \, \delta(r) = 1$.
3. What mathematicians do: Describe the charge density using a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), rather than a conventional function. (This is really just a more rigorous version of option 2.)

This is one of those cases where you can essentially ignore the mathematical subtleties, because, if you do everything rigorously, things turn out more-or-less as you would have expected. (There are obviously plenty of examples where this is not the case, and what appear to be annoying mathematical details turn out to be important physical subtleties in disguise.)

Comment: Comment to the answer (v1): Note that option 2 to treat the delta function as a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty]$ that is zero [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) is mathematically problematic since the Lebesgue integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}x~f(x)=0$ of such a function (as opposed to a distribution) is zero (as opposed to one) by conventional definitions in measure theory.

Comment: I hate to open the comment like this, but as a mathematician, I tend to like the mathematical subtleties :)  

I understand that you'd like to use a delta function or a distribution as rho. However the equivalence has a distribution and/or delta on the one hand, and a function (the divergence of E which has a definition everywhere but a single point). So this would mean that you have made a distribution into a function (or vice versa).